# Can you use 洗うwhile talking about a specific part you are washing while showering?

Tags: nuances, verbs

Usually you use 浴びる for showering or bathing (not too sure about bathing) right? 
And you use 洗う for washing in general right?
Can you ever use 洗う in a shower/bath scenario like my example below?

例：シャワーをあびた時、下の所が特に洗った。(disclaimer: sentence might contain errors)

While I was showering, I especially washed my nether regions.

Comment: I can't answer your question, but I assume you meant 下の所**を** rather than 下の所**が**?

Answer (score 10):

In that situation, you could use 「洗{あら}う」 quite naturally if you inserted 「特{とく}によく」 or 「よく」 and say:

> 「シャワーをあびた時{とき}、下{した}の方{ほう}を特によく洗{あら}った。」.

It would sound more natural to use 「方」 over 「所{ところ}」.

To further intensify the adverb, you could use 「集中的{しゅうちゅうてき}
に」("intensively") and say:

> 「シャワーをあびた時、（特に）下の方を集中的に洗った。」

Finally, as we all know, Japanese has an onomatopoeia for every human action and for "washing hard", it is 「ゴシゴシ（と）」.  With that, you could say:

> 「シャワーをあびた時、下の方を特にゴシゴシと洗った。」